# Ejecución de query con global secondary index

Tags: nodejs, aws, lambda, dynamodb

Buen día.
De que manera puedo ejecutar una consulta en una lambda hecha con nodeJs tomando la global secondary index.
Actualmente tengo esto, lo cual me ejecuta por medio de la primery key:
La BD esta hecha con dynamoDB en AWS.

```
const idUser = "1";
    let scanningParameters = {
            Key: {
               id: idUser
            },
            ProjectionExpression: 'id, username, password, name',
            TableName: 'users'
      }
```

Con id obtengo el username y password, ahora lo que requiero es lo mismo pero obtenerlo con el name.
He intentado esto:

```
const name = "myName";
    let scanningParameters = {
        TableName:"users",
        KeyConditionExpression: "name =:Name",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {":Name": name}
      }
```

Alguna sugerencia o solución, de antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

si el nombre no es una key ni sort key; deberas usar un scan, pero esto te saldrá más costos de dpu. otra cosa que puedes hacer es, crear otra tabla en donde la key sea el nombre, y la id sea un atributo. pero claro, como condición es que cada nombre sea único.

te dejo un ejemplo obtenido de https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-query-scan.html

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js.
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
// Set the AWS Region.
AWS.config.update({ region: "REGION" });

// Create DynamoDB service object.
var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: "2012-08-10" });

const params = {
  // Specify which items in the results are returned.
  FilterExpression: "Subtitle = :topic AND Season = :s AND Episode = :e",
  // Define the expression attribute value, which are substitutes for the values you want to compare.
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":topic": {S: "SubTitle2"},
    ":s": {N: 1},
    ":e": {N: 2},
  },
  // Set the projection expression, which are the attributes that you want.
  ProjectionExpression: "Season, Episode, Title, Subtitle",
  TableName: "EPISODES_TABLE",
};

ddb.scan(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", data);
    data.Items.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
      console.log(
          "printing",
          element.Title.S + " (" + element.Subtitle.S + ")"
      );
    });
  }
});
```